# Javascript - string comparison failing

Tags: javascript, string, utf-8

I am comparing two strings

```
if (sPHText == sPhSpanText) {     //"Sample " === "Sample "     comparison fails
                return true;
             }
```

The comparison fails if both the strings have space at the end. **sPHText** is read from a an xml file and **sPhSpanText** from html page. If there are no spaces it works fine. I am wondering this is due to encoding issues. If I use trim it works.

How can I make it work?

Comment: If trim make it work, why don't you use it?

Comment: There is probably an invisible character in one of the strings?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon That is one of the case, i need to validate space in other case for some other purpose

Comment: Try to replace every whitespace character with a space : `sPhSpanText.replace(/\s/g, ' ');`

Comment: `"Sample " === "Sample "; // true`. Check the _length_ and if that's still a match, see where the difference is using `string.charCodeAt(index);`, you might have different types of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string must have different whitespace character such as normal space or non-breaking space.

You can replace all your whitespace with a regular space :

```
sPhSpanText.replace(/\s/g, ' ');
```